# oozie run example error: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://**/user/ubuntu/share/lib, expected: file:///

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Recently, I have been investigting oozie and trying very hard to build a local oozie system.After reading the official web page again and again, I finally made it. But when I tried to run a example in `examples/` direction, I always got an error:

```
2016-07-21 21:55:17,936  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[namenode] USER[ubuntu] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-160720220441466-oozie-ubun-W] ACTION[0000001-160720220441466-oozie-ubun-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [ERROR], ErrorCode [IllegalArgumentException], Message [IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://166.111.81.254:9000/user/ubuntu/share/lib, expected: file:///]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://166.111.81.254:9000/user/ubuntu/share/lib, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:445)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://166.111.81.254:9000/user/ubuntu/share/lib, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1525)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getLatestLibPath(ShareLibService.java:687)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.updateShareLib(ShareLibService.java:551)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getShareLibJars(ShareLibService.java:346)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getSystemLibJars(ShareLibService.java:412)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addSystemShareLibForAction(JavaActionExecutor.java:721)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addAllShareLibs(JavaActionExecutor.java:818)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.setLibFilesArchives(JavaActionExecutor.java:809)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1037)
    ... 10 more
2016-07-21 21:55:17,939  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[namenode] USER[ubuntu] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-160720220441466-oozie-ubun-W] ACTION[0000001-160720220441466-oozie-ubun-W@mr-node] Setting Action Status to [DONE]
```

The error bothered me for a few days and I've been trying to solve it. If you have any suggestion, please teach me~ Thanks for it very much!

My configuration are AS FOLLOW：

**hadoop**

*core-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://166.111.81.254:9000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ubuntu.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ubuntu.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

*yarn-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>166.111.81.254</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>166.111.81.254:54311</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

*hdfs-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop-2.6.4/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**oozie**

*oozie-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.root.configurations</name>
      <value>*=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.4/etc/hadoop/</value>
      <description>
          Comma separated AUTHORITY=HADOOP_CONF_DIR, where AUTHORITY is the HOST:PORT of
          the Hadoop service (JobTracker, HDFS). The wildcard '*' configuration is
          used when there is no exact match for an authority. The HADOOP_CONF_DIR contains
          the relevant Hadoop *-site.xml files. If the path is relative is looked within
          the Oozie configuration directory; though the path can be absolute (i.e. to point
          to Hadoop client conf/ directories in the local filesystem.
      </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
    <value>hdfs://166.111.81.254:9000/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
    <description>
        System library path to use for workflow applications.
        This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
        the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.ubuntu.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.ubuntu.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: That error message typically means that your YARN container did not set the correct CLASSPATH. The Hadoop `Configuration` constructor searches the CLASSPATH for **directories** and searches these directories for the required `*-site.xml` *(just like Log4J does when searching for its properties file)*. If `Configuration` does not find the XML files, then it reverts to hard-coded default (starting with `fs.defaultFs = FILE:///`) **without any warning**.

Comment: Hmm... on second thoughts, the error shows in the Oozie server logs, not in the YARN logs for the Action. So maybe the CLASSPATH issue applies to your Oozie server itself...! Make sure it contains `/etc/hadoop/conf` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! I'm new fish in hadoop and oozie, I read many blogs and set the configuration for the hadoop and oozie. From your answer, i can tell that I should add the hadoop configuration direction to the `CLASSPATH` ? Really glad to receive your answer. Thank you !